# How do I make emacs treat '_' as a normal character, not a separation one?

Tags: emacs

I want emacs to treat '_' as a normal character, not a separation one. The purpose for that is navigation. When I jump by word, I end up in the middle of the variable.

For example, if I have a variable 'manu_variable', and the cursor is at the just before the variable, and I do Ctrl+Right, it jumps at the end of 'manu' instead of jumping at the end of 'variable'. How do I fix that? I want to move whole variables when jumping by words.

Comment: This is configured in the syntax table for the mode you are in. Do you want to customize this mode (which one?) or are you looking for a way to override the global default syntax table? The former is easier, at least in terms of possibly unintended side effects.

Comment: I use emacs for c++ and python, so it's c++-mode and python-mode.